# Why won't this virus be removed by Microsoft Security?

Tags: windows, security, virus, virus-removal

I don't know how but Windows Security still detects such virus unlike other anti-virus softwares.
[image]

Comment: You will have to delete the contents of your temp file off line

Comment: Also, it will be removed if you wish and if you click on Actions and select remove / quarantine.

Comment: No, it didn't work  . @John

Comment: Should I delete the temp folder in safe mode for example? @Moab

Comment: You can run Disk Cleanup to clean up temp files. If the file above is still there, yes try Safe Mode.

Comment: better to do it offline, malware will prevent deletion in safe more or regular mode. But this could cause other issues like not booting, back up your important date before doing anything,

Comment: @Moab I did it offline in safe mode and it worked. But I had to repress the remove  button after restarting.

Comment: Just... one thing.. Do you have a User called "Windo"? Seeing that file location - that is not in the standard Temp folder path... it almost as if you have a user called Windo - and the files are there. Since the path are visible - just go and manually delete it.

Comment: Yes it is my username but I didn't understand your solution @Darius.

Comment: “I don't know how but Windows Security still detects such virus unlike other anti-virus softwares.” - Its probably a false positive.  You should submit the file so Microsoft can improve their AV engine.  You can also submit it to Google’s website to get the results from multiple different AV engines

Comment: I think it's already automatic https://prnt.sc/v1zecz
But the files are deleted now.
@Ramhound
But how does it take for them to update their AV engine?

Comment: No; You need to submit the file yourself.  You need a Microsoft account to do it also.  Yes; That submits a sample; But why I am talking about is a manual submission

Comment: A Potentially Unwanted App, which the warning is about, is not the same thing as a "Virus". And it is strictly a matter of subjective opinion as to whether an app should be so classified. The Windows Defender is known to make some very questionable judgments in that area.

Comment: @kreemoweet To be honest, It's just a crack's leftover as I added only “program files (x84) and program files and downloads” folders in Windows Defender as an exception.

Comment: That’s a horrible idea...